# Access Denied with PsExec on remote machine using OpenEdge driver for Progress

Tags: c#, odbc, openedge, psexec, progress-db

I have a remote machine (let's call it *Target*) on which the driver OpenEdge 10.1B is installed (communication with Progress database).

I have an exe on this remote machine that connects to the Progress database through the driver. When i log onto this machine (rdp) with my windows account 
 then I test this executable file, i can see that **it connects** to the database **successfully**.

What i need to do is execute this exe remotely, from a machine, call it *Source*. For this, I use [PsTools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pstools). 
Note that I execute this code logged with my windows account (on the same domain than the machine *Target*)
Below is the c# code I use to execute this file.

```
public static bool Execute(List<string> tablesNames)
        {            
            //the process to start
            const string processName = @"C:\script\MyProgram.exe";
            var serverName = "theServerName";
            //params for MyProgram.exe
            var param = "-s " + String.Join(" ", tablesNames);

            try
            {//example: c:\pstools\psexec.exe \\theServerName C:\script\MyProgram.exe -s tableName1 tableName2
                //Start the process
                ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\PsTools");
                info.LoadUserProfile = true;
                info.FileName = @"C:\PsTools\psexec.exe";
                info.Arguments = $@"\\{serverName} {processName} " + param;
                info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                info.UseShellExecute = false;
                Process p = Process.Start(info);

                Console.WriteLine( "Program " + processName + " was started correctly.");
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine( ex.ToString());
                return false;
            }
        }
```

The error I get on the log of the machine *Target* is:

> ERROR [IM003] Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error
>   5: Access is denied. (OpenEdge 10.1B driver, [...]

Notes:

- the datasource is a 32-bit system DSN on machine Target.
- Both *Source* and *Target* machines are 64-bit.

As I previously said, executing MyProgram.exe works well when i run it directly from machine *Target*.

Any ideas on what I may have done wrong ?

Comment: I'd start by creating a batch echoing the PATH to a file, I'm thinking path is set wrong when psexec is running it.

Comment: thanks @bupereira i tried to call a batch file instead, and it is called without any problem : the syntax seems to work here.

Comment: I just edited the question, as in my original post, there was a copy/paste mistake : the error i really get is about denied access from the openedge driver.

Comment: According to these links, it seems to be a folder permission problem. They're not OpenEdge related, but the error seems to be common in remote connection environments. Check this out, even if just to rule out this issue:
https://forums.asp.net/t/1614927.aspx?Head+Banging+ODBC+Problem
And this one
https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213372069-Connection-to-MySQL-database-fails-Specified-driver-could-not-be-loaded-due-to-system-error-5-Access-is-denied-MySQL-ODBC-5-1-Driver-